# get the size of an array using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I've the below data in a json file.

```
{  
   "product":"Data",
   "data":{  
      "zip":[  
         {  
            "codeValue":"12345",
            "distance":[  
               {  
                  "5":"a c"
               },
               {  
                  "2":"z c"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "codeValue":"60089",
            "distance":[  
               {  
                  "5":"a c"
               },
               {  
                  "2":"z c"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

and I'm trying to print the `zip` size using the below code.

```
public void getJsonResponse() throws Exception {
    String text = getTheData();
    System.out.println(text);
    ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> map = objMap.readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });

    String mainMap = map.get("product").toString();
    String getData = map.get("data").toString();
    Map<String, Object> map1 = objMap.readValue(getData, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
    });
    List zip = (List) map1.get("zip");
    System.out.println(zip.size());
}
```

here instead of `sysout` on `zip.size()`, if I used `mainMap`, I get the output as **Data**, but when I use `zip.size()`, I get some exception as

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('z' (code 122)): was expecting double-quote to start field name
>    at [Source: java.io.StringReader@60f82f98; line: 1, column: 3]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1524)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:557)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportUnexpectedChar(ParserMinimalBase.java:475)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._handleOddName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1293)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser._parseName(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:1190)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.ReaderBasedJsonParser.nextToken(ReaderBasedJsonParser.java:612)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer._readAndBindStringMap(MapDeserializer.java:412)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:312)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:26)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2993)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2105)
>       at onlyJava.JsonDataCAll.getJsonResponse(JsonDataCAll.java:24)
>       at onlyJava.Test.main(Test.java:13)

please let me know where have I gone wrong and how can I fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String getData = map.get("data").toString();
```

This won't return a JSON to you and hence the exception. You will get something like {zip=[{...

Instead change your statement from

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = objMap.readValue(getData, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {
        });
```

to

```
Map<String, Object> map1 = (Map<String, Object>) map.get("data");
```

Comment: I've a quick question, how can I get the `"codeValue": "12345",
                "distance": 5` value?

Comment: Your List is a List<Map<String,Object>>. So you can do something like Map<String, Object> map2 =(Map<String, Object>) zip.get((INDEX HERE); Than map2.get("codeValue"). Similarly map2.get("distance"); will give you a list. Than List is again a map and the key of that map is your distance i.e "5"

Comment: Hey 1 last thing, how can I do this in a `for(type var: var)` loop?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the question. For loop on zip or distance?

Comment: on zip, basically i want my solution to be where the zip and distance are entered, first there would be a loop for the zip and then a loop for distance, and the answer is returned back

Comment: If your JSON structure is fixed, I would say better map your JSON to a POJO. It will be easier for you to do any processing. But if it's not fixed than maybe something like this will help you: 
`for (Map<String, Object> map2 : zip) {
syso("codeValue " + map2.get("codeValue"));
List<Map<String, Object>> distance = (List<Map<String, Object>>) map2.get("distance");
for (Map<String, Object> map3 : distance) {Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> iterator = map3.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {syso("DISTANCE : " + iterator.next().getKey());}}}`

Answer (score 1):

You make conversions that could be skipped. Try this:

```
Map data = (Map) map.get("data");
List zip = (List) data.get("zip");
System.out.println(zip.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

cast as ArrayNode

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;

ArrayNode zip = (ArrayNode)data.get("zip");
System.out.println(zip.size());
```